# CodeWars: Gap in Primes

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, programming-challenge, primes

I wrote JavaScript code for finding the first two consecutive prime numbers (that doesn't have divisors except one and itself) with a specific gap between them. It works well but take too much time to give results for large numbers.

When I tested this, it took about 48s to give the result:

> gap = 8 ,start = 3,000,000 and end = 4,000,000

I read about how to cache to minimize access for properties as length and put variables in local scope to make the code more efficient, but it didn't help me a lot. I then tried to optimize the `for` loops, but it affects the functionality of the code.

[Link to challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/gap-in-primes/train/javascript)

```
function gap(gap, start, end){
 var arr = [];
 var counter = [];
 var result;
 for(var x = start; x <= end; x++){
  if(x % 2 == 1){
   arr.push(x)
  }
 }
 for(var cache = arr.length, j = cache ; j >= 0; j--){
  for(var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(arr[j]); i++){
   if(arr[j] % i === 0){
    if(i != arr[j]/i || i * i == arr[j]){
      counter.push(arr[j] / i)
      arr.splice(j, 1)
      break;
    }
   }
  }

  if((arr[j+1] - arr[j]) == gap){
   result = [arr[j], arr[j+1]]
  }else if (result == undefined){
   result = null
  }
 }

 return result
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order of significance for performance

- Don't use array to store prime numbers. You only need one previous
  prime to remember. And even if you ever do this, don't remove
  elements from its middle, as shifting array contents is very costly.
- Store number from expensive `Math.sqrt()`, don't re-calculate it every iteration. Basically, this is rule for every loop - precalculate limits if possible.
- There is only one even prime number: `2`. It gives you great opportunities to quickly remove some edge cases:
- If gap is odd, only `2` can be a first number. This condition is worth checking at the very start of your function
- If number is greater than `2`, it can be prime only if it is odd. This allows you to skip half of testing numbers by increasing counter by `2` each iteration, not just `++`
- Prime testing can be further improved by using `6k ± 1` pattern. It saves you one extra check every 3 odd numbers
- You are testing prime numbers in loop. Create a function for this, `isPrime` or something

```js
function gap(gap, start, end) {
  //cut off odd gaps
  //bitwise AND can test least significant bit
  //odd numbers have 1, even have 0
  if (gap & 1) { //is it odd?
    if (start > 2 || end < gap + 2) return null; //check if 2 is in range
    return isPrime(gap + 2) ? [2, gap + 2] : null; //check additionally the other part
  }
  var previous = null; //no initial value
  //loop over odd numbers to check for primes
  for (var current = start | 1; //set last bit to 1: /odd numbers stay same, even numbers become next odd
       current <= end;
       current += 2 // skip any even number
      ) {
    if (isPrime(current)) {
      if (current - previous === gap) //is it a match?
        return [previous, current];
      //no need for "else" here as the other branch has "return"
      previous = current; // anyway, save it
    }
  }

  return null; //no early return from loop = nothing matches

  
  /**
    Tests if n is prime
  */
  function isPrime(n) {
    if (n <= 6) //cut away small primes explicitly
      return n === 2 || n === 3 || n === 5;
    //cut away small divisors (2 and 3) explicitly
    if (n & 1 === 0 || //using bitwise AND for even numbers
        n % 3 === 0) return false;
    
    var limit = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); //precalculate loop limit
    // loop is checking every divisor using 6k ± 1 pattern
    for (var t = 5; //start with 5, first 6k - 1 number
         t <= limit;
         t += 6 //step by 6
        ) {
      if (n % t === 0 || //6k - 1
          n % (t + 2) === 0) //6k + 1
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
console.log(""); //this makes console output timestamp
console.log("gap(8,3000000,4000000)", "->", gap(8,3000000,4000000)); // ~5ms
console.log("gap(120,3000000,4000000)", "->", gap(120,3000000,4000000)); // ~600ms
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/blr_Oliver/krhu8cuk/). I submitted it on *CodeWars*, it passes :)

Comment: Could you please comment your code.

Comment: @Abdel-Raouf, enjoy

Comment: Why you used a bitwise operator "|", how could these improve the performance?

Comment: `current = start | 1` is a replacement for whole `if...else...` statement. It runs in single CPU tick, doesn't use branching and doesn't use arithmetics.

Comment: why do you also use '&' in 'gap & 1', how it checks for being odd or not? i don't understand the behaviour.

Comment: [Binary mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Querying_the_status_of_a_bit)  (you see, it's just a number) can filter bits from testing number only on positions where mask has. I'm interested only in the last bit, so I apply mask consisting only of this very bit. It appears to be just number `1`. Why do I need only last bit? Because it essentially separates even and odd numbers.

Comment: you are the most efficient code and cover a lot of test cases with huge improvement in performance,i now also know how to use bitwise in my code, i will accept you as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a huge problem in your code!
You are iteration from start to end and push every `x % 2 == 1` into an array. Alone that takes a long time (with values between 3e6 to 4e6)!

So I wrote it completely new for you :)

```js
function isPrim(x) {
 if (x === 2) return true; // as @Graipher commented
 if (x % 2 !== 0) {
  // you only need to check to the half of x
  for (var i = 2; i <= x / 2; i++) {
   if (x % i === 0) {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function gap(g, m, n) {
 var lastPrim = null; // cache-value
 // now the 'trick', check not every number to n
 // when you found the gap, you have it and then you can return with the result
 for (var i = m; i < n; i++) {
  if (isPrim(i)) {
   if (lastPrim === null) {
    lastPrim = i;
   } else if (i - lastPrim === g) {
    return [lastPrim, i];
   } else {
    lastPrim = i;
   }
  }
 }
 return null; // no result was found
}
console.log(gap(2, 0, 10)); // [1, 3]
console.log(gap(2, 2, 10)); // [3, 5]
console.log(gap(4, 0, 20)); // [7, 11]
console.log(gap(6, 100, 110)); // null
console.log(gap(8, 3e6, 4e6)); // [3000953, 3000961]
```

You can copy past it to codewars, it passes all tests

Edit: we found out that this solution is good and easy to understand, but when you have large gaps Oliver's improvements are taking part.

Comment: @Graipher fixed, but it runs all tests on codewars. And also, this wasn't the problem of Abdel-Raouf

Comment: Well, then they didn't think of that test case :D

Comment: 1-why you return false before quitting the isPrime function, 2-why you assign null to lastPrim variable.

Comment: @Abdel-Raouf 1-because if i found that x isn't prim, I can break out of the loop, 2-because it is cleaner and i check `if lastPrim === null`, I can also check `if lastPrim === undefined`

Comment: I found a very interesting thing: 1-when I change my `var`'s to `let`'s it is ~0.5ms slower, 2-my solution is 1.5-1.8ms faster than Oliver's answer,  but he uses so much 'improvements' | (everything tested in jsfiddle + gap(8, 3e6, 4e6) + console.time() and console.timeEnd() Chrome 55)

Comment: @Shinigami, try it on long run. Test with `gap =  8` runs only over 500 numbers to find first match. Try `gap = 120` to see the difference. And yes, `let` is usually slower than `var`

Comment: @Oliver wow, very fascinating! with 500 yours runs with 2ms agains my with 78ms ^^

Comment: could you please tweak your english a little bit, as it cause me difficulty to understand it the first time i read as 'check not everything to end' and 'than' .

Comment: @Shinigami, I started your code 4 minutes ago, and it is still running, for `gap(120, 3e6, 4e6)`. Are you sure for those 78ms?

Comment: @Oliver gap(120, 3e6, 4e6) => 77.486ms

Comment: @Abdel-Raouf sorry for my english, I'm german. I have fixed the mistakes you named.

Comment: @Shinigami, are you running code submitted here? At my computer *jsfiddle* page with your running code just crashed silently after 10 minutes, producing no output.

Comment: @Shinigami, could you please make it runnable snippet, right here at *stackoverflow*? There is an option for javascript code in editor

Comment: @Oliver Yes, I tried it again. Everything is fine?! Do you missed anything by coping it?

Comment: @Oliver, i try your code and it's faster a lot when it tests long range of numbers as gap = 120 , on the other hand the code of 'Shinigami' still run for a long time without any results.

Comment: @Shinigami, see it yourself on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blr_Oliver/ns563m09/). I didn't include test with 120 as it doesn't even complete

Comment: added an edit to the bottom of my answer

Comment: -1 for incorrectly claiming that pushing half a million numbers to an array takes "a long time" (in chrome, that takes < 0.01 seconds).